# UDP server_client. Using Socket object inside asyncio coroutines there's no concurrency

Tags: python, sockets, concurrency, udp

I have a hard time understanding the whole concept of asyncio. For now i try to make a UDP chat working as server and client at the same time with the use of the Socket module and asyncio together. Inside two asyncio coroutines i run loops (one for the server and one for the client). But the program works only as client. Sending data at the network but not receiving. I guess that there are much better asyncio solutions for this case but before proceeding to them i'd like to understand why doesn't the SPECIFIC code work. Do you have any clues?

```
# PYTHON 3.4
import asyncio
import socket

PORT = 50001
MAX_BYTES = 8400
LOCAL_IP = ''
REMOTE_IP = '192.168.1.31'

serverSock= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSock.bind(('', PORT))

@asyncio.coroutine
def server():
    while True:
        data, address = serverSock.recvfrom(MAX_BYTES)
        print('New data: {}'.format(data.decode('utf8')))

@asyncio.coroutine
def client():
    while True:
        toSend = input('Enter to send: ')
        serverSock.sendto(toSend.encode(),(REMOTE_IP, PORT))

tasks = [server(), client()]
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

Comment: i'm imagining the while loop blocks the event loop, for whichever task is scheduled first.

Comment: Yes but why is it blocking? Whatever is inside a coroutine is supposed to run concurrently with the others. That's why i use asyncio..

Comment: it's not yielding in any way, i've never used asyncio but it needs some way to yield to the event loop when nothing is happening, something like `data, address = yield from serverSock.recvfrom(MAX_BYTES)`

Answer (score 0):

The whole coroutine + event loop principle relies on a concept called `Cooperative multitasking`. Meaning that is a coroutine is irresponsible and decides to consume all the cpu for itself, nothing will interrupt it in doing so.

Both of your coroutines are like that, they never end on their own. A context switch will occur automatically during a blocking call if you're using multiple threads, but in the coroutines example you have to explicitly use `await` to give up the cpu.